# Generic method returning a List while instantiating the generic Type passed in the method

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

I have been struggling for quite a bit of time and have looked up on a few resources trying to comprehend how could i use generics to get what i am trying to achieve but have not been able to find an example that provides what i need .

Some examples included the use of [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--) Interface or have suggested having a generic class and then instantiating it .

What i am trying to achieve is to specify the Type i want the method to return while Instantiating the same type in the method and adding it to the list and then return that list .

Thanks in advance . Would appreciate any help

```
public List<Doctor> queryDoctor() {
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet results;

    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DOCTOR);

        List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<>();
        while (results.next()) {
            Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
            doctor.setId(results.getInt(1));
            doctor.setUserName(results.getString(2));
            doctor.setPassword(results.getString(3));
            doctor.setPassword_salt(results.getString(4));
            doctor.setRole(results.getInt(5));
            doctors.add(doctor);

        }
        return doctors;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Query failed: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass in a `Function<ResultSet, T>`, and have that function create the `T`(e.g. `Doctor`).

Comment: I personaly prefer to write an abstract class with generic method like this calling abstract method for each row (buildInstance) and implement a class for `Doctor` to create the instance and get the parameter in the correct order. If the alternative is intersting, I will provide an answer.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow I am trying to populate a table .. Instead of having different methods for each actor (e.g Doctor,Nurse,Receptionist) i want to achieve it with a single method  as all of the actors share the same attributes and no not at runtime

Comment: have you seen commons-dbutils' QueryRunner https://github.com/apache/commons-dbutils/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/dbutils/QueryRunner.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to pass in a `Function<ResultSet, T>`:

```
<T> List<T> queryDoctor(Function<ResultSet, T> fn)
```

and use this in the loop:

```
doctors.add(fn.apply(results));
```

This function would create the appropriate concrete type:

```
List<Doctor> doctors = queryDoctor(results -> {
       Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
        doctor.setId(results.getInt(1));
        doctor.setUserName(results.getString(2));
        doctor.setPassword(results.getString(3));
        doctor.setPassword_salt(results.getString(4));
        doctor.setRole(results.getInt(5));
        return doctor;
});
```

or

```
List<Nurse> nurses = queryDoctor(results -> {
       Nurse nurse = new Nurse();
       // ...
       return nurse;
});
```

Comment: I am not sure because i want to instantiate the same object type .For the case that if i need a Nurse,doctor,Patient's List  to be returned  then it instantiate the Nurse or the doctor or the patient  in the method. Please explain

Comment: Then pass in `results -> { Nurse nurse = new Nurse; /* do stuff to populate nurse */ return nurse }` as the function.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting your own simple ORM solution where you supply a method with an SQL string and a type, the method loads the results and then instantiate the type, mapping the result set to the object's fields via setters.

If so, you're reinventing the wheel.

A full solution would be to use an ORM tool like Hibernate or Top Link but that might be running before you can walk. If you prefer baby steps, consider using Spring's Jdbc Template to handle a lot of the boilerplate code.

UPDATE

OK,I asked if you were looking for a method that took a resultset and mapped it to an arbitrary class and you said yes. This should do something like that:

```
public <T> List<T> map(ResultSet rs, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    //// Build a list of columns that are in the resultset
    List<String> columns = new LinkedList<>();
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    for(int i=0; i < metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        columns.add(metaData.getCatalogName(i));
    }

    //// Create a list to hold all the beans we are going to create from the resultset 
    List<T> rows = new LinkedList<>();

    //// Iterate over each row in the resultset, creating beans for each row and setting the values 
    while(rs.next()) {
        //// Create a new instance of the class passed in (must have a no-args constructor) 
        T row = clazz.newInstance();

        //// Now for the magic. This bit is very noddy and ORM packages will do this much better 
        for(String col : columns) {
            //// For each column that is in the resultset, find the setter in the bean class 
            String columnValue = rs.getString(col);
            String mutator = "set"+capitalizeFirstCharacter(col);
            Method m = clazz.getMethod(mutator, String.class);
            //// Invoke the setter, passing in the value from the resultset 
            m.invoke(row, columnValue);
        }

        rows.add(row);
    }

    return rows;
}

private static String capitalizeFirstCharacter(String s) {
    return s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
}
```

Beware that this code does not deal with exceptions, only works with resultsets filled with Strings and only deals with beans that have String fields to populate. Once you start trying to write more complex code to deal with more complex types and reflection... you are reinventing ORM. Try not to do that.

Comment: Using Hibernate to only get a POJO from one table would be terribly heavy. The configuration, the time spend to learn... The complexity added when a pure JDBC solution can be done easily seems unnecessary. A solution but not a generic solution.

Comment: @Ramsay Yes but i have heard about hibernate and spring but this is for my university project and i have not worked with the technologies you have mentioned

Comment: So are you trying to create a general-use method that can turn SQL into collections of objects, as I suggested?

Comment: @RamsayDomloge Yes